# How can I make a javascript function work for many expandable cards in html and css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a list of cards, when i click in "more info" I want expand the content individually. How I can achive this with Javascript

'https://codepen.io/nikoocrow/pen/oNqaBEe'

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is an HTML5 semantic element that does exactly this, without any javascript at all. It is called Details.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details

Here is an example:

```
<details>
  <summary>More Info</summary>
  <p>We specialize in all sorts of great work.</p>
</details>
```

Then it just becomes a matter of styling the details, rather than implementing specific javascript logic.